# How to Route With Dynamic Controller Name in Laravel 4.2

Tags: dynamic, controller, routes

I got this :

```
http://local/service/get/data/module_01/act_01
http://local/service/get/data/module_02/act_01
```

Every Module has a Controller (**Module01Controller**, **Module02Controller**).

I've try this but no luck.

```
Route::any('/service/get/data/{mod}/{cond?}', function($mod, $cond=0) {
    $controllerDir = strtolower($mod);
    $controllerName = ucwords($mod).'Controller';
    Route::get('/service/get/data/'.$mod.'/{cond?}', $controllerDir.'\\'.$controllerName.'@data');
});
```

Can i have this routing-case in **just one Route** ?

Comment: Did you try ? What is the problem ?

Comment: If you would like some help, you should describe and give as much details you can (logs, network capture, ...)

Comment: sorry, just added routes.php